# R Shiny: Custom styling of dynamically created bucket_lists

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a function that dynamically creates multiple bucket lists dependent on prior inputs without manually creating each `add_rank_list`.

However, I have not been able to style it, as with non-dynamic creation of bucket lists.

The following example demonstrates this.

It is styled with a HTML tag. `class = c("default-sortable", "custom-sortable")` is then included as an option within `bucket_list`. However, I cannot place this code without error in the dynamically created bucket_lists' code.

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    HTML("
                                                      .rank-list-container.custom-sortable {
                                                       border-color:#FFFFFF;
                                                      }
                                                      .custom-sortable .rank-list-item {
                                                      border-color:#FFFFFF;
                                                      }
                                                      ")),
   uiOutput("bucket_1_and_2"),
  
 fluidRow( column(6,uiOutput("bucket_1")),column(6,
  uiOutput("bucket_2")))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  bucket_1 <- reactive({lapply(c("Default","Styling"), function(x) {
    add_rank_list(
      text = "",
      input_id = paste0("bucket_1_",x),
      labels =  x
    )
  })
  })
  output$bucket_1_and_2 <- renderUI({
    do.call("bucket_list", args = c(
      header = "",
      group_name = "bucket_sort",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      # The following code does not function:
      # class = c("default-sortable", "custom-sortable"),
      bucket_1()
    ))
  })
  
  
  output$bucket_1 <- renderUI({
    bucket_list(
      header = "",
      group_name = "bucket_sort",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      class = c("default-sortable", "custom-sortable"),
      add_rank_list(
        text = "",
        input_id = "bucket_1",
        labels = "Custom"
      ))
  }
  )
  output$bucket_2 <- renderUI({
    bucket_list(
      header = "",
      group_name = "bucket_sort",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      class = c("default-sortable", "custom-sortable"),
      add_rank_list(
        text = "",
        input_id = "bucket_2",
        labels = "Styling"
      ))
  }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `do.call`? If you really need that, try to set a list to the `args` argument: `args = list(......)`. Also, I never used `bucket_list`, but usually one sets the `class` attribute of a HTML element as a single character string, separating the classes with a white space: `class = "default-sortable custom-sortable"`.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the code as per your comments. However, an error still persists: ```Warning: Error in : is_add_rank_list(x = dot) is not TRUE```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used `bucked_list` so I'm not sure, but perhaps you want:

```
output$bucket_1_and_2 <- renderUI({
  bucketLists <- lapply(bucket_1(), function(x){
    bucket_list(
      header = "",
      group_name = "bucket_sort",
      orientation = "horizontal",
      class = c("default-sortable", "custom-sortable"),
      x
    )
  })
  do.call(tagList, buckedLists)
})
```

Comment: Amazing, @Stéphane Laurent. Thanks very much.